# Why is app:assembleDebug called twice?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Why is `app:assembleDebug` called twice during my builds?

My app consists of two modules, the application module `app` and a library module `commons`. When I click ‘run’ in Android Studio to deploy the app on the device, I see this happening:

- The bottom bar says `Gradle build using tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :commons:assembleDebug]`. The blue progress bar is slowly filled. No output in the Gradle Console.
- At 100% progress, I get the notification `Compilation completed succesfully in 3m`. Yay! At this point I expect the app to be installed.
- The bar is stuck at 100%. For a moment I read something like `executing post-compile tasks`, and then `Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]`.
- `:app:assembleDebug` is called again and takes some other 3 mins, while we are stuck at 100%. This time the Gradle Console logs output.
- The app is installed.

Why is this? *Not using Instant Run, though the same thing applies*.

#### gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560M
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

#### project level build.grade

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 25
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### app module build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.id"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release_config
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1'
    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.1') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-tasks'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.14.0'
    compile ('com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'parse-android'
    }
    compile project(':commons')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, somehow I had this in my run configuration:

[image]

After removing `Make`, I am back to sane compilation behavior. I wonder why I had that extra make though.